# Dynamically rendered nested inputs lose their value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am new to using `react-hook-form` and noticed something that I can't seem to prevent. When a component is dynamically rendered, the value of its nested input components don't hold their value.

My component structure is:

```
  ParentComponent
    --> ChildComponent(s)
      --> Controller component (supplied via react-hook-library)
```

Here is a sandbox to reproduce the problem - https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-http-i574n.

I could solve this problem by placing all my code into one component and use CSS to dynamically show them. However, that would make for a very big component file so trying to avoid this.

*Note I have a feeling this is expected behaviour since the Controller unregisters the ref when it unmounts.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. Instead of dynamically rendering the component to instead pass the show value to the component and set this to the `hidden` HTML attribute.

So instead of doing this:

```
//ParentComponent
return (
   {displayInput && <CustomInput />}
)
```

I have done this and it keeps the values.

```
//ParentComponent
return <CustomInput hidden={!displayInput} />

//CustomInput
return (
  <section hidden={hidden}>
    //content
  </section>
)
```

I have a concern that as the form grows, this won't be a scalable approach. Ideally, I would conditionally render these components, rather than conditionally make them `hidden`.